# android app crashes on launch when i try to declare an intent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-pendingintent

please help

```
val snoozeIntent = Intent(this, SnoozeReceiver::class.java).apply {
        action = "ACTION_SNOOZE"
        putExtra("EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID", 0)
    }
```

i'm trying to follow the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Actions

my broadcast class:

```
class SnoozeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val REQUEST_CODE = 0

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS

        val notifyIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            alarmManager,
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime,
            notifyPendingIntent
        )

        val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
            context,
            NotificationManager::class.java
        ) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancelAll()
    }

}
```

Android manifest :

```
<receiver
                android:name=".receiver.SnoozeReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_SNOOZE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Use `Intent().apply` instead

Comment: Thanks so much @Md.Asaduzzaman it worked but now it's happening with the next line of code which is 
```
val snoozePendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)
```
can you also tell ne the reason why is this happening i'm new to android environment

Comment: From where you try to implement this? Please add more details of your implementation

Comment: Are you initializing this variable outside of a method? If so, that's your problem. You need to initialize the variable after your `Activity` (or whatever) has been completely constructed (ie: after `onCreate()` has been called).